# Side scrolling game background

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, parallax

I am working in Cocos2d and xcode to create a side scrolling game.

I have an issue with my coding for adding a background to the levelscene.
I tried to implement a parallax background to no avail so have opted to just have a background the player will scroll across.

But at the moment the background follows the player across the screen, which frankly looks rubbish.

The code I have is

```
(void)setupParallax {

NSString *backgroundName = [self.tilemap propertyNamed:@"BackgroundImage"];

CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:[AssetHelper getDeviceSpecificFileNameFor:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"background-noon.png]]];
background.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0);
background.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);

[self addChild:background z:0];
}
```

I know it must be something with either the position or anchorPoint but these values only change with reference to the screen they are loaded on.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [this tutorial on doing parallax scrolling](http://www.raywenderlich.com/33752/) in cocos2d-x?

You an do parallax scrolling by hand...but it will probably easier, at least if you are just starting out, to do it using the CCParallaxNode and let the framework do the heavy lifting for you.